# Can't update to iOS 13.5 over hotspot

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, software-update

I've been trying to update my iPhone to iOS13.5.1. I couldn't find an option to update via Mobile Data (and apparently it's not supported), so I tried to create a hotspot through another phone and update my iPhone over that. However, it is not updating.

Is there a workaround for this? Can I somehow lead my iPhone to believe that the mobile hotspot is a WiFi connection?

PS: In the settings corresponding to the network, I've set Low Data Mode to off.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. What do you mean by "it is not updating"? Is there an error message? Or does it start updating and then aborts?  Does this answer your question? [Does iOS download iOS updates when using a hotspot?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322410/does-ios-download-ios-updates-when-using-a-hotspot)

Comment: @jaume what I meant was, it gets stuck at 'estimating time remaining'. There's no error message. I left it for like 12 hours but no update was either downloaded or installed.

Comment: iOS updates are large, couldn't it simply be that the update needs a long time to download over a hotspot because, for example, the cellular connection is throttled after a while? That's why Apple recommends using Wi-Fi in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but I saw that  this is a known issue with iOS13 updates. I was wondering if someway I could trick my iPhone to believing that it was connected to a WiFi rather than a Hotspot?

Comment: I’m also getting the same issue with it stuck at “Estimating time remaining...” trying to update from iOS 13 over a hotspot. Unfortunately they closed this question even though the answers in the linked question do not solve the problem. Still wondering if there’s a solution.